# Apply the Blaschke Selection Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, convex-geometry, hausdorff-measure

Let the sequence of convex  $n$-gons $\{P_k\}$. Is there a subsequence $\{P_{k_i} \}$ of that sequence such that $P_{k_i} \to P$ as $k_n  \to \infty $, where $P$ is a $m$-gon for $m \leq n$ ? I think the Blaschke Selection Theorem is an option for the resolution of that problem, but I am not quite sure how to resolve with that result. Could anyone be able to help me at this point? Particularly, why $P$ must be an $m$-gon in such a way that $m \leq n$?

> **Blaschke Selection Theorem :** For a sequence $\{K_n\}$ of convex sets contained in a bounded set, there exists a subsequence
>   $\{K_{n_m}\}$ and a convex set $K$ such that $K_{n_m}$ converges to
>   $K$.

**Clarification :**  The limit is endowed with the usual Hausdorff metric.

Comment: @Vim That result is a true result from the article The sound of Symmetry (Proposition $6$ page $820$). I was wondering how to use the following theorem.

Comment: Your $n$ is fixed? Then what is $P_{k_n}$?

Comment: Yes, n is fixed, and $\{P_{k_n} \}$ is a subsequence of $P_k$.

Comment: technically you should use another letter other than $n$. By the way, by *bounded* polygons do you only mean the polygons are *uniformly* bounded, or in a stronger sense, they are all contained in a bounded set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is not true since you can take $P_k = kP$ where $P\neq \{0\}$ is any $n-$ gon. 
But if you assume that there exist a ball $B$ such that $P_k \subset B$ for infinitely many $k.$ Then it is true. To see this let $A_k =\{p_{k1} , p_{k2} ,  ... p_{kn}\} $ be the set of vertices of the $n-$ gon $P_k .$ Then there exists a sequence of natural numbers $s_j $ such that $p_{s_j l} \to p_l $ for all $1\leq l\leq n$ as $j\to \infty $, where $p_l \in \mathbb{R}^d .$ 
From the inequlity $$d_H (\mbox{conv} (A) , \mbox{conv}(B) ) \leqslant d_H (A,B)$$ we obtain that $P_{s_j } \to \mbox{conv}\{ p_1 , p_2 , ..., p_n\} $ as $i\to \infty$ with respect to the Hausdorff metric $d_H .$

Comment: Could you tell me why in the question $m \leq n$? Why is there exist a sequence of natural numbers $s_j$? And you mean probably $j \to \infty$ at the end, right?

Comment: Moreover, you mean probably by " *if you assume that there exist a ball $B$ such that $P_k⊂B$ for infinitely many $k$*" that the set of $P_k$ is compact, right?

Comment: $m\leqslant n$ because some of the poins $p_l$ may be equal each other. Yes, there should be $j$ instead of $i$. No, the sentence " if you assume that there exist a ball $B$ such that $P_k \subset B$ for infinitely many $k$ ' implies that the set $\mathcal{B} =\{P_k :k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ contains an infinite compact subset with respect to the Hausdorff metric.

Comment: Why is there exist a sequence of natural numbers $s_j$?

Comment: Moreover, could you clarify the notation "conv"?

Comment: Since every bounded sequence of points of finite dimensional normed space poses a convergent subesequence. $\mbox{conv} (S) =\bigcap \{M : S\subset M, \mbox{and } M \mbox {is convex}\} $